# Docker container only running when launching from Docker Desktop (not command line)

Tags: docker

I've created a Docker image using Github Actions and am able to pull the image down (using the full name: username/repo_name/tag). It shows up on my Docker desktop and if I run a container from there, it works. However, if I try to run the container from my command line I keep getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for container_name, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

Any thoughts on why this may be the case? I'm relatively new to Docker and appreciate any advice!

Comment: Is that a private image or public?

Comment: It's a public image

Comment: Hey delroro, please could you phrase the question for this post as a question? It helps people to answer your question more easily, thanks.